# How can I combine multiple query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some queries like that:

```
select sysdate from dual;
select id, count(*) as A from TABLE1 group by id;
select id, count(*) as B from TABLE2 group by id;
select id, count(*) as C from TABLE3 group by id;
select id, count(*) as D from TABLE4 group by id;
```

How can I combine that 5 queries like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could union together the four tables in a meaningful way and then do a conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SYSDATE,
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C,
    SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D
FROM
(
    SELECT id, 'A' AS label
    FROM TABLE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'B'
    FROM TABLE2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'C'
    FROM TABLE3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 'D'
    FROM TABLE4
) t
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Or `COUNT(CASE WHEN label = 'D' THEN 1 END) AS D`, so as to get nulls as shown in the desired result.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am usually scared of `COUNT` because of the way it deals with NULLs.  Hence, I gravitate towards SUM instead.

Comment: Sum getting just 0 or 1. But I have more than when I use count(*).

Comment: Without you showing us some sample data, I can't help much beyond this.  Are you sure the output of my query is not what you expect?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake. I forgot group by into subquery. It's work now, thank you.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Oops, that was nonsense. You are right about `COUNT`. It is `SUM` that can return nulls. Hence: `SUM(CASE WHEN label = 'D' THEN 1 END) AS D`. My `COUNT` expression gives the same result as your `SUM` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this by using `union` keyword.

Comment: Right information, wrong format.  The OP wants each table count in separate columns.